# Show title on hover on gallery image thumbnails CSS

Tags: css, hover, gallery, rollover, squarespace

I have a gallery of images and am trying to get a simple hover of an ID number/title for each image. I don't need a fancy transition or anything (it would be too hard for me to do tbh), just the title to appear when I mouse over it. My site is with Squarespace and they can't help as it's seen as advanced programming.

They have a custom css code section that you just paste the coding into. Don't think you put anything in the head section, just the css into this bit of the site. This is the code someone used to fade the images on rollover. (They said the main element is the first line).

```
.sqs-gallery-design-grid-slide:hover {
 -webkit-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000); 
-moz-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000); 
-ms-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000); 
 -o-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000); 
    transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000);  
     opacity: 0;

     }
```

All I'm looking for is to change it to show image titles on hover instead of fading the image. When you upload each image you can name it, is there a way through CSS to tell it to pick up this info to appear on hover?

I know **nothing** about CSS coding but have tried for almost a fortnight to learn enough to do this myself, and I'm lost. Any help at all would be very much appreciated! 
Thanks

Comment: do you mean the title attribute? or you need a custom tool-tip?

Comment: The important question is where is the title in the HTML code (element/attribute). You can't dynamically add text on hover via css, you can just show or hide existing elements in the HTML.
We need this code to help you.

Comment: I believe it's using the title attribute, I just don't know where to put it in the above coding so it would pick it up

Comment: You could inspect the html code of your gallery and post it in your question.

Comment: I don't think I have access to the html of the gallery as it's a drag and drop one within a template and they limit what you can access. They did give these instructions to make a simply hover gallery here: http://photogs.squarespace.com/ but they have since changed from Squarespace 5 to 6 and it no longer works. This is the exact thing I'm wanting though. I'm just wondering if it's any use?

Comment: You always have access to the final html output because it's what the browser needs to display your page. Something like "right click" -> "view source". You can't edit it from there  (at least not long term) but it helps to understand what's needed in your css.

Comment: Each thumbnail shows this: <div class="slide" data-type="image">
              <div class="margin-wrapper">
                <a
                                      data-title=""
                    data-description=""
                    href="http://static.squarespace.com/static/513a230ae4b0f3422dd7d5ad/5140ae67e4b0a5e36012e886/5140af15e4b0a5e36012ec45/1363193727277/3.jpg"
                    
                  class="image-slide-anchor content-fit"
                >

Comment: <img data-load="false" data-image="http://static.squarespace.com/static/513a230ae4b0f3422dd7d5ad/5140ae67e4b0a5e36012e886/5140af15e4b0a5e36012ec45/1363193727277/3.jpg" data-src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/513a230ae4b0f3422dd7d5ad/5140ae67e4b0a5e36012e886/5140af15e4b0a5e36012ec45/1363193727277/3.jpg" data-image-dimensions="1600x2400" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" alt="3.jpg"  data-image-id="5140af15e4b0a5e36012ec45" />
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>      Sorry had to split into 2 msgs as was too long.

Answer (score 3):

I see only one css only sollution for this. And this even works only if you would be able to put your title into the `a` element like this:

```
<a title="Picture 1 TEST" rel="lightbox" href="http://photogs.squarespace.com/simple/gallery-1/2706700">
```

With css you then could grab the content from the `title` attribute on the link. Which works in most browsers exept IE7-. Unfortunately `:after` seems not to be supported on `img` elements.

```
.thumbnail-wrapper a {
  position: relative;
}
.thumbnail-wrapper a:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  color: #000;
  padding-left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity:0.5;
  min-height: 30px;
  background: #FFF;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

This would look like that:

[image]

Comment: Yes that's what I'm after. I can't understand why Squarespace make it so awkward to be able to do this. Marcel you've been so helpful thank you so much. Will find out if I can put the title in the a element and then can see if it works. Thank you again for taking the time to help me. I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Squarespace, but any kind of title/name you give the image is saved in some kind of database and you would need to retrieve that name somehow in order to display it, with or without the help of css. Also, what you want is normally achieved by putting any desired image title into the `alt` or `title` attributs of the `img` tag, i.e.: `<img src="example.jpg" alt="Here is hover title" title="Here is hover title" />` Different browsers would use on or the other.